# How to find second <p> element in a <div>?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Which CSS selector matches the second paragraph without using an ID?

```html
<div>
  <p>Apple</p>
  <p>Mango</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21):

You could use the [`nth-child` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), set to find the second child. This will select all `<p>` elements that are the second child of their parent:

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Apple</p>
  <p>Mango</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Apple</p>
  <p>Mango</p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you want to find the second child in a specific set of elements, you could wrap those elements in a `<div>`:

```css
#wrapper p:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Apple</p>
  <p>Mango</p>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Apple</p>
  <p>Mango</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

My preference in this situation would be to use the `:nth-of-type` pseudo-class:

```
div p:nth-of-type(2)
```

---

**Why choose `:nth-of-type` over `:nth-child`?**

Because `:nth-of-type` is ***explicitly*** intended for situations (like the one you describe) where you wish to select the nth of a *specific element type* within a given context.

---

**See this Working Example:**

```css
div p:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>Fruit Bowl</h2>
<p>Apple</p>
<p>Mango</p>
</div>
```

---

**But I can still  use `:nth-child` instead, right?**

Yes you can - but it  might not always give you the result you are expecting.

The syntax `div p:nth-child(2)` ***doesn't*** mean every second `p` in a given context inside the `div` (like `div p:nth-of-type(2)` does).

Instead it means an element which is a `p` and which is *also* a second child.

Knowing that, which `p` do you guess will be highlighted in the example below?

```css
div p:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>Fruit Bowl</h2>
<p>Apple</p>
<p>Mango</p>
</div>
```

Did you guess right?

Do you now understand the difference between `:nth-of-type(2)` and `:nth-child(2)`?

Comment: While I agree, I think it is a good idea for you to explain *why* this is your preference, as that explanation would help reveal why your answer is more appropriate as the answer to OP's question than the other, existing answers.

Comment: Yes, fair enough @TylerH. Amongst CSS beginners and pre-intermediates, there is often a little confusion between `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type`. A longer, more detailed explanation (which I've now provided) was not surplus to requirements.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `nth-child`.

```
p:nth-child(2) {  
  color: #ccc;
}
```

REF: [How nth child works](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works)